# Combining a project made in Django with a RESTful API using Django-Rest-Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

We have a project that was developed by using Django, and we want to develop a mobile application out of one part of that project(not entirely the whole project).

From my own understanding, RESTful APIs are used to be the backend of mobile applications. So we want to build this API as an app inside the django project using Django-RESTful-Framework.

So my question is, **is it okay to build an API inside an already made Django Project?**

Because the RESTful API will need models of that project. For now, we already have a problem of accessing the api endpoint from the mobile app because the django project we developed was using sessions and it responses with 403 forbidden.

Comment: Yes, rest framework is meant to be used inside django, it's not a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

ABSOLUTELY! DRF is an awesome package, and if you need to power a mobile app through an API off the same models, this is the way to go. Of course it is an opinion thing, but I think that DRF's strength is that it is easy to get up and running with, but allows some really in depth control when needed.

If you are getting a 403, it is tough to say why without seeing any code. Take a look at this: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/